# Extracting corresponding Values in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find rows in `su19$q2` marked "Yes", and from there find its corresponding value (names of schools) in `su19$q1`.  However, everything I am trying seems to not work.

```
su19$q1[su19$q2 == "Yes"]
```

I do not understand why this is not working.

My expectation is that for every "Yes" response in q2, a list is returned of its corresponding school from column q1.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example ?

Comment: is `q2` actually a character string ?

Comment: @Mike yes, q2 is a character string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am creating a new answer as adding code is not possible in comments

```
su19 <- data.frame(q1 = c("Santiago Canyon College","College of 
       Alameda","Cerritos College","Cuyamaca college","Cypress College","Folsom Lake 
       College"), q2= c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes"),stringAsFactors= FALSE)

                        q1  q2
 1 Santiago Canyon College Yes
 2      College of Alameda Yes
 3        Cerritos College Yes
 4        Cuyamaca college Yes
 5         Cypress College Yes
 6     Folsom Lake College Yes
```

@Chelmy88 solution

```
su19$q1[which(su19$q2 == "Yes")]
[1] "Santiago Canyon College" "College of Alameda"      "Cerritos College"        "Cuyamaca college"        "Cypress College"        
[6] "Folsom Lake College"
```

my solution

```
su19[which(su19$q2 == "Yes"),]$q1
[1] "Santiago Canyon College" "College of Alameda"      "Cerritos College"        "Cuyamaca college"        "Cypress College"        
[6] "Folsom Lake College"
```

If you don't have a `data.frame`, but vectors only

```
q1 <- c("Santiago Canyon College","College of Alameda","Cerritos College","Cuyamaca college","Cypress College","Folsom Lake College")
q2 <- c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes")

su19$q1[which(su19$q2 == "Yes")]
[1] "Santiago Canyon College" "College of Alameda"      "Cerritos College"        "Cuyamaca college"        "Cypress College"        
[6] "Folsom Lake College"
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems when I put the labels into variable, I receive a NULL output but when I level the col name in its original state, I receive the output I am looking for.  thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
su19$q1[which(su19$q2 == "Yes")]
```

The which() function returns the indices where the given vector is "True". In your example the expression su19$q2 == "Yes" returns a vector of either True of False depending if the equality holds or not (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/which)

Comment: same result, but instead of working with vectors, I would return the entire row and select only the column I need `su19[which(su19$q2 == "Yes"),]$q1`. I found it more versatile as I have more control on the output.

Comment: Thank you, but when I put in either of these it returns NULL.

Comment: Can you then please show us what you have in su19 ?

Comment: I am not sure how to format the table in Stack overflow but in: q1, there is a list of school names (e.g. Hancock College, Marin College, Portland College); in q2, it is either yes or no.

Comment: You can provide the output of `head(su19)`(which displays the first lines) and of `typeof(su19)` (which tells the object type)

Comment: check if `class(su19$q2)` returns `character`. If not try to convert it to a character vector `su19$q2 <- as.character(su19$q2)`, and re-run @Chelmy88 command

Comment: @fra Yes, the class for q2 is character.

Comment: Name of School
1 Santiago Canyon College
2      College of Alameda
3        Cerritos College
4        Cuyamaca college
5         Cypress College
6    Folsom Lake College 
  Is this a Corrections to College School?
1                                      Yes
2                                      Yes
3                                      Yes
4                                      Yes
5                                      Yes
6                                      Yes

Comment: I put Name of school into a variable q1; and Is this a Corrections to College School? into q2

Comment: It would be useful if you can really provide us with q1 and q2, e.g with `dput()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))